# Let f continuous function in [0,2] Such that $f(2)=3$ Prove that exist $c \in (0,2) , f(c)=1/c$

Tags: functions, continuity

> Let f continuous function in [0,2] Such that $f(2)=3$ Prove that exist
> $c \in (0,2) , f(c)=1/c$

I tried to use Intermediate value theorem

defined $g(x) = f(x)-1/x $

then $g(2) > 0 $

and I need to find another $x_0 \in [0,2]$ such that $g(x)<0$ and then I get that exist $c \in (x_0,2)$ that $g(x)=0$ but I don't know how to find $x_0$ .

any hint will help me

thanks

> answer thanks to @mathworker21 :
>
> Let $():=()$
>
> then $g$  is continuous and  $$g(0) = 0f(0) = 0  < 1$$ $$g(2) = 2f(2)
> > = 6  > 1$$
>
> so by Intermediate value theorem exist $c\in (0,2) $ such that :
> $$g(c)=1$$ $$g(c)=cf(c)=0 \rightarrow f(c) = 1/c $$

Comment: Let $g(x) := xf(x)$. Then $g$ is continuous and $g(0)=0, g(2) = 6$. So there's some $c \in (0,2)$ with $g(c) = 1$, i.e., with $f(c) = 1/c$.

Comment: Also, $f(x)-\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy thats correct my bad even if I define the function $(0,2]$ still has nothing to do with it I think mathworker21 answer is better thanks for you both I"ll edit the question with mathworker21 answer

Answer (score 1):

Since f is continuous, f([0,2]) is closed and bounded by Heine Borel theorem. But $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{1}{x}\to +\infty$ so $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=-\infty$ which implies $\exists$ a small $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)<0$ by continuity of $g$ .